# Eye Detection using javascript and html5

Tags: javascript, html, eye-detection

Does anyone have any ideas or steps or algorithms for performing Eye Detection on 2d images using javascript and HTML5?

I have already done converting RGB to YCbCr color space

Now I need some help on eye extraction

```
function hellow(e)
{
    var r,g,b,a,gray;
    var imageData = ctxBg.createImageData(gameWidth,gameHeight);
    var das =imageData.data;

    for(var i=0;i<=800;i++)
    {
        for(var j=0;j<=640;j++)
        {
            var d = (j*imageData.width+i)*4;
            var helow = ctxBg.getImageData(i,j,1,1);
            r=helow.data[0];
            g=helow.data[1];
            b=helow.data[2];
            a=helow.data[3];
            das[d]=Math.round((0.299 *r) - (0.168935*g) + (0.499813*b));
            das[d+1]=Math.round((0.587 *r) - (0.331665*g) + (0.418531*b));
            das[d+2]=Math.round((0.114 *r) - (0.50059*g) + (0.081282*b));
            das[d+3]=a;
            console.log(das[d]+":"+das[d+1]+":"+das[d+2]);
        }
    }
    ctxBg.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
    //console.log('c');
    e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

That's my code for converting the rgb to YCbCr color space.

Please help me also improve the code for faster execution.

Comment: You're telling me that code does eye extraction? That's incredible

Comment: No hes telling this code does RGB to YCbCr convertion

Comment: I don't recommend to do such a task client-side. Client-side scripts are ideal to make the interface more usable, not for heavy image manipulations.

Comment: how about the code up.. is there any way to make the scope chain less?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What i did recently trying to solve same problem was:

1. Scale down processed image to achieve decent performance (I downscaled everything to 320px width)
2. Detect face in image using Core Computer Vision Library - https://github.com/liuliu/ccv
3. Based on the detected face rectangle information detect eyes using HAAR object detector (it has cascade for eyes only detection - https://github.com/inspirit/jsfeat

For step 2 i also used "grayscale" and "equalize_histogram" from JSFEAT library.

Also if step 3 fails you can try to guess eyes position (depends on how high accuracy you're going for).

This workflow gave me satisfying results and performance. It tested it both on desktop (~500ms on iMac) and mobile devices (~3000ms on iphone 4 using image from webcam).
Unfortunately I cannot post a link to working example at this point, but i'll post a link to github once i have something there.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [tracking.js](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/tracking.js) to detect eyes using various techniques from a real scene captured by the camera.

Once you import the script with the library and add the canvas to the HTML you can do something like:

```
var videoCamera = new tracking.VideoCamera().hide().render().renderVideoCanvas(),
    ctx = videoCamera.canvas.context;

videoCamera.track({
    type: 'human',
    data: 'eye',
    onFound: function(track) {
        for (var i = 0, len = track.length; i < len; i++) {
            var rect = track[i];
            ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0,255,0)";
            ctx.strokeRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.size, rect.size);
        }
    }
});
```

The code above comes from one of the examples in the library.
Hope that help you

Comment: This library is very nice but quite resource hungry. Do you know any other which is just for the purpose of eye and face tracking it delivers a better performance?

Comment: See my just updated https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect#performance performance comparison for fast eye *detection* libraries. For pure eye *tracking*, stay with tracker.js though or adapt the camshift algorithm found in https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr.

Answer (score 3):

I daresay that luminance only could be enough to  detect eye / face position - so you can make your code faster by just dripping computation of CbCr.  One usually looks for yeas / faces using Haar cascade:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know if something specifical is implemented only for eye detection, but for face detection you should look after a library named as Core Computer Vision Library, which is hosted on github: https://github.com/liuliu/ccv.

Another possibility would be https://github.com/inspirit/jsfeat, where face, and pixel edge detection is implemented using different algorithms, like Lucas-Kanade optical flow and HAAR object detector.

Please read this post for further techniques: [Face detection javascript/html5/flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913928/face-detection-javascript-html5-flash/10915471#10915471)

Answer (score 2):

There is an example of eye detection (with custom eye haar openCV cascades) in pure javascript/html5 using the [HAAR.js](https://github.com/foo123/HAAR.js) library (ps i am the author).

The project is stopped, no new features added, but it does what it states.

Answer (score 1):

For eye detection use OpenCV.js , check this [Human Eye Detection using Javascript and OpenCV](http://www.recompile.in/2019/11/human-eye-detection-using-javascript.html)

```
let faceCascadeFile = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml';

let eyeCascadeFile = 'haarcascade_eye.xml';

utils.createFileFromUrl(faceCascadeFile, faceCascadeFile, () => {

    utils.createFileFromUrl(eyeCascadeFile, eyeCascadeFile, () => {

    console.log('eye cascade ready');

    })
})
```

Example

[image: eye detection]